# nvidia-smi problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-smi
```

I get

```
The nvidia-smi package is a virtual package provided by:
  nvidia-387 387.34-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2
  nvidia-384 384.98-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1
You need to explicitly select one to install.
```

How do I choose one of these two to install?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You choose one package or the other by supplying the package name to `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-387
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: You can install both packages (`nvidia-smi` and the Nvidia graphics drivers) with a single command if you add them both to the `apt-get install` command.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the recommended driver open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers. The output of this command will be a list of the package names and short descriptions of the available drivers. In addition to showing a list of the available drivers, the above command will often also identify the **recommended proprietary driver**(s) for your system.